# I cant download and upload my react native project because the .git file its to large

Tags: git, react-native, gitlab

I'm using react native to build a project, and its hosted in a gitlab repository, but the project its know so large (because de .git folder ([PIC .git FOLDER SIZE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymMNh.png))) and I can't clone it! I'm working with a download data limit... E Have a local branch, and I cant upload this for other repository because the file its too big... This folder got to occupy 2GB, I researched and tried to reduce it, and I managed to reduce it to 666MB, as in the photo. However, it is still very big!

Please, help meee

[PIC GITLAB FOLDER SIZE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LNjP.png)

Comment: Surely you're not also storing binaries in your Git repository, right?

Comment: How i know that i'm doing that?

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce the size is to remove the `node modules` directory.